# VK SDK doesn't register when using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vk

How can I change this

```
[[VKSdk initializeWithAppId:@"3974615"] registerDelegate:self];
```

to Swift

```
VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("5234446")
```

it is my version, but is doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the documentation for the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This can't work,
you must add (self, andAppId:)
like

```
VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "3974615")
```